# Yii2:Sum three input fields and assign result to fourth one

Tags: forms, yii2, sum, yii2-advanced-app

i am having four fields as shown in code. i want to sum the `night_firsthotel`,`night_secondhotel`,`night_thirdhotel` and assign result to `total_night`.

How would i do this?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'nights_firsthotel')->dropDownList(range(1, 10)); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'nights_secondhotel')->dropDownList(range(1, 10)); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'nights_thirdhotel')->dropDownList(range(1, 10));  ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'total_nights')->textInput(['readOnly'=> true]) ?>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use js with dropdown onchange

Comment: Any one can give example of how i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nights_firsthotel = Html::getInputID($model, 'nights_firsthotel');
$nights_secondhotel = Html::getInputID($model, 'nights_secondhotel');
$nights_thirdhotel = Html::getInputID($model, 'nights_thirdhotel');
$total_nights = Html::getInputID($model, 'total_nights');

$this->registerJs(<<<JS
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function () {
            var total_nights = 0;
            total_nights += parseInt($('#$nights_firsthotel').val()) || 0;
            total_nights += parseInt($('#$nights_secondhotel').val()) || 0;
            total_nights += parseInt($('#$nights_thirdhotel').val()) || 0;

            $('#$total_nights').val(total_nights);
        });
    });
JS
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
First you need to set a ID to the input dropdown , if it has  you can change the  id  that i writed an put yours.

And second you need to access to this with JS and sum the values  and  set to the "total_nights" input.

I writed the code but I do not proved  . Try and  tell me

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'nights_firsthotel')->dropDownList(range(1, 10) ,    ['id'=>'nights_firsthotel']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'nights_secondhotel')->dropDownList(range(1, 10),    ['id'=>'nights_secondhotel']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'nights_thirdhotel')->dropDownList(range(1, 10),    ['id'=>'nights_thirdhotel']);  ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'total_nights')->textInput(['readOnly'=> true,'id'=>'total_nights']) ?>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {

        var nights_firsthotel = document.getElementById("nights_firsthotel").value;
        var nights_secondhotel = document.getElementById("nights_secondhotel").value;
        var nights_thirdhotel = document.getElementById("nights_thirdhotel").value;
        var total_nights = document.getElementById("total_nights");
        total_nights.val(nights_firsthotel+nights_secondhotel+nights_thirdhotel);
    });
});
```